# How exactly does InsertAllOnSubmit works in Linq

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql

I have two tables Products and Order for some reason I just want a few records to come and sit in Orders table
I have the following code

```
public ActionResult Order()
    {           
        List<Product> products=TempData["products"] as List<Product>;
        List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();
        Order order = new Order();
        foreach (var item in products)
        {
            order.Customer_Id = 1;
            order.Product_Name = item.Model_Name;
            order.Amount = item.Price;
            order.Order_Date = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
            orders.Add(order);
        }                 
        db.Orders.InsertAllOnSubmit(orders);            
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View(products);
    }
```

I just want to know how does it work found some stuff online but couldn't understand how really it works. Can anyone could tell how  it works nad how to apply it in the above code

Comment: when you call db.SaveChanges(), the insertion operations to database take place. before that, they only exist in your context. (in application memory)

Comment: @IsThatSo But how they are inserted using   InsertAllOnSubmit(orders) and how  to implement this method.

Comment: Move the `Order order = new Order();` to the inside of the loop. Because it is outside of the loop at the moment, you are **not** inserting new elements in the loop, rather, you modify the very same element.

Comment: @WiktorZychla if I modify as per you and also if I remove db.Orders.InsertAllOnSubmit(orders) still it is not getting saved within database. Any other conclusion

Comment: Do not remove the `InsertAllOnSubmit`

Comment: sorry, i wasn't aware that this isn't working. just move `Order order = new Order();` into foreach loop and it should be fine. if not, we need the exception details.

Comment: @WiktorZychla ok fine but what should be there within that method as I don't have any definition for that

Comment: @IsThatSo plz let me know the implementation of InsertAllOnSubmit() how does it work

Comment: we cannot know that. it's not open source as I know.

Comment: @IsThatSo  and if I use it then it says an error 'are you missing an assembly....'

Comment: Add a reference to `System.Data.Linq`

Comment: @IsThatSo added the reference but still no progress display the same error msg

Comment: please provide the rest of the error message 'are you missing an assembly....'

Comment: @IsThatSo Here is the error  'System.Data.DbSet<ShopOnline.Models.Order>' does not contain a definition for InsertAllOnSubmit and no extension method 'InsertAllOnSubmit' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DbSet<ShopOnline.Models.Order>' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @WiktorZychla plz check the error msg

Comment: The error message suggests that you call the method in a wrong way, however, it looks correct in the above snippet. Are you sure you have copied the snipped from your actual code?

Comment: @WiktorZychla yeah I copied as it is.

Comment: @WiktorZychla is there any other way for that. If I don't use the InsertAllOnSubmit and try to insert, it doesn't give any error and  even  the record is not getting inserted.

Comment: Take a look at my answer, specifically at the very last sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why it doesn't compile, according to the discussion under your question you possibly paste some other code, however this should definitely work:

```
public ActionResult Order()
{           
    List<Product> products=TempData["products"] as List<Product>;

    foreach (var item in products)
    {
        Order order = new Order();
        order.Customer_Id = 1;
        order.Product_Name = item.Model_Name;
        order.Amount = item.Price;
        order.Order_Date = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
        db.Orders.Add(order);
    }                 

    db.SaveChanges();
    return View(products);
}
```

Edit: note that since you are calling `SaveChanges` rather than `SubmitChanges` Then most probably you are **not using** linq2sql but rather, the Entity Framework and you are just confusing these two!

The `InsertAllOnSubmit` is not implemented in EF, you just use the code I suggest above.